# "Fastclick.js" cause the cursor of "textarea" cann't be located in the text and select the text,Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, fastclick.js

`Fastclick.js` cause the cursor of `textarea`  can't be located in the text and select the text,Why???

```
<textarea  placeholder="<?= $ret['reply'] ? '' : '分享新观点'; ?>" id="comment-content"  class="fs-16 bg-fff" oninput="chkInput()" onpropertychange="chkInput()">

   <?= isset($ret['topic']) ? $ret['topic'] : "" ?><?= $ret['content']; ?>                     

</textarea>
```

I have added all these classes

```
class="needsClick fs-16 bg-fff" 
class="needsFocus fs-16 bg-fff"       
class="noFastclick fs-16 bg-fff"
name="noFastclick"
```

But all these doesn't work.

How to make "fast click" not affect the textarea???

Answer (score 0):

The class looked by fastclick is `needsclick`, all lower case.